# Installing vmware on Linux

Tags: terminal, vmware

when i was installing vmware this what happen

[zsh: unknown file attribute: b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmyG8.png)

`file Downloads/vmware.bin Downloads/vmware.bin: a /usr/bin/env bash script executable (binary data)`

what can i do to solve this problem and install it on my PC